# No matching function for call in c++ using header file

Tags: c++, class

My program keeps sending error message just on this part :

```
#include "StockListType.h"

int main()
{
int menuPromptOption;
double gainLossList[5];
StockListType stockList [5]; //error part
stockType A,B,C,D,E;
}
```

And here is the header file I'm using for the main

```
class StockListType : public listType<stockType>
{
public:
    StockListType (int size);
    void sortArrayByGain();
    void sortArrayByGain(double arrayList []);
    void printByGain();

    ~StockListType();
    }
```

this is the error message that I keep receiving.

```
error: no matching function for call StockListType::StockListType()
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] please? There's a *lot* of stuff you are not showing us here.

Answer (score 2):

The following line in your `main`:

```cpp
StockListType stockList [5];
```

is instructing the compiler to create an array of 5 `StockListType` objects using the *default constructor* for that class for each object.

However, as you have explicitly defined a non-default constructor in the class, with this:

```cpp
public:
    StockListType (int size);
```

then the compiler will *not* generate a default constructor (that is, one that takes no argument).

To resolve this, you need to add an *explicit* default constructor:

```cpp
    StockListType ();
```

And, of course, provide an actual *definition* for that elsewhere in your code (or add  `= default` in the declaration). Exactly what that default constructor does is up to you but, if it does much the same as the other (which you already have), then you could 'merge' the two by providing a default value for the `size` argument:

```cpp
    StockListType (int size = -1); // Default value for "size" allows use as a default c'tor
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.